# How do I migrate an AWS RDS MySQL database to PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I currently have a MySQL AWS RDS instance, that I'd like to migrate over to PostgreSQL so that I can get off AWS and use Heroku instead.

I've tried PGLOADER,and when I enter in what I think is my MySQL database URI (mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database) and the provided PostgreSQL URI from Heroku, I get an error saying that there's no such file or directory "mysql://username:password".

I have also tried Pentaho, and I can get PostgreSQL to connect, but when I try to connect to my MySQL RDS instance, Pentaho times out, and I'm not where the my.ini file mentioned in [this article](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MySQL) is located at in order to fix it.

Any other options for migrating from MySQL to Heroku Postgres would be very appreciated.

Comment: How about using something like https://github.com/ggarri/mysql2psql ? 
More generally, if it's a small database without functions and stuff, tools from github should do the work to transfer the data+schema. 

Another way is to use AWS DMS, you can dynamically edit data, but depending on your budget... it's aws, costly.

Comment: Did you provide inbound access to **all traffic** of your RDS's security group. time out is because of access denied.